# The issue with using Rollup.js

Tags: typescript, rollupjs

I'm learning TypeScript and want to use export/import mechanism. I have 3 .ts files and the code looks as following:

1) MyClass.ts:

```
/// <reference path="../Scripts/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/dx.all.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/go.d.ts" />

export class MyClass {
    render(divId: string, text: string): void {
        ...
    }
    getData(): void {
        ...
    }
}
```

2) Caller.ts:

```
import { MyClass } from './MyClass';

export class Caller {
    execute() {
        let myClass: MyClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.render("content", "Hello World");
        myClass.getData();
    }
}
```

3) Main.ts:

```
import { Caller } from './Caller';

window.onload = () => {
    let caller: Caller = new Caller();
    caller.execute();
};
```

4) HTML:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/MyClass.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Caller.js"></script>>
<script src="~/Scripts/Main.js"></script>
```

5) tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "outDir": "../Scripts",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
        "module": "commonjs"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "wwwroot"
    ]
}
```

As I understand the last step is to use some module loader or module bundler. I've picked up module bundler Rollup.js. Again, as I understand Rollaup.js should produce one bundle file that will contain all TypeScript (JavaScript) code I wrote. Is that right?

If so, I've downloaded Rollup.js and went to Scripts sub folder of my MVC 5 web application where are all .ts, .d.ts, .js and other files. I use in my TypeScript code JQuery, DevExtreme and GoJS JavaScript libraries as well.

After that I use the following Rollup command:

```
rollup Main.js -o bundle.js -f cjs
```

I've understood that Main.js file was entry point and Rollup will automatically resolve export/import dependencies and create 1 output bundle.js file that I can use in this way in HTML code:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/bundle.js"></script>
```

The bundle.js file created, but there is nothing except for the content of Main.js file. So, in this way my apllication displayes nothing.

The code I've shown here is just for presentation the issue purposes and the real code is more complex.

What I did wrong?

Comment: In the meantime I've figured out how to create single bundle.js file using webpack, but I'll leave this post if someone can help with Rollup.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [rollup-plugin-typescript](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-typescript) rather than pre-compiling your .ts files — [here's an example config](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/typescript-lib/blob/master/rollup.config.js). (To use a config file, run `rollup -c`.)